# elastic collission

Tags: collision

During an elastic collision some of the macroscopic kinetic energy is transferred to kinetic energy of the microscopic parts of the colliding bodies.

The momentum is conserved, so the sum of the momenta if all the particles in the system is the same before and after collision. The kinetic energy of the sum of all the particles of the system must also be the same or else some kinetic energy has disappeared into nothing. The kinetic energy of the bodies have decreased.

Is there not some kind of contradiction in these facts. If the total microscopic kinetic energy is the same before and after collision, and both bodies have lost macroscopic kinetic energy and transferred into microscopic kinetic energy then this seems contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no contradiction. Momentum and energy are both conserved on a fundamental, microscopic level. That means when you look at point-particles which have no rotational or vibrational degrees of freedom their momentum and kinetic energy is always conserved in total. If you account for all the momenta and kinetic energies of the atoms of the macroscopic bodies, their sum is conserved processes.

This changes when you include rotational and vibrational degrees of freedom. If you allow your microscopic particles to vibrate, the macroscopic body will be unchanged. The total momentum does not change, but the kinetic energy has changed. Usually we perceive this vibration as heat.

The important observation is that momentum is linear in the velocity ($p = mv$) whereas the energy is quadratic in the velocity ($E = m v^2/2$). This also means that the sign of the velocity if important whereas it does not matter for the energy. This means that the following states have the same *total* momentum:
$$p_1 = P \,,\quad p_2 = - P \qquad \text{and} \qquad p_1' = 2P \,,\quad p_2' = - 2P \,.$$
The total momentum in both cases is zero as you can see by adding $p_1$ and $p_2$ up. However, the kinetic energy is different in the cases. In the first case, the kinetic energy is $E = 2 \cdot P^2/(2m)$ and in the second it is $E' = 2 \cdot 4 P^2/(2m)$. The kinetic energy in the second case is a factor four higher as in the first case although the total momentum is still zero.

In the collision the total momentum never changes. The energy is not uniquely determined by the total momentum, though. You can have parts inside each of the bodies vibrate in opposite directions. They will have zero total momentum but can have arbitrary kinetic energy.

With this mechanism you can lower the apparent macroscopic energy of the bodies involved in the collision. However, the energy is still conserved on the microscopic level. It has to go somewhere. The energy ended up in the vibration (heat) of the bodies. Therefore the $m v^2/2$ kinetic energy has lowered for the bodies, but the energy is still there.

On a microscopic level you can think of a body moving as a bunch of atoms all moving. And they mostly move in the same direction because the body as a whole moves in one direction. This motion is mostly ordered because the velocities are mostly parallel. If the temperature of the body was zero, then all the velocities would be equal and parallel. After the collision the velocities are not as parallel as before, they are now a bit more disordered. This means that the overall velocity of the body has been reduced and its heat has gone up. However, the energy is still conserved on a microscopic level.

Comment: But what about the fact that microscopic kinetic energy before and after collision are the same AND macroscopic kinetic energy have been transferred into microscopic kinetic energy ?

Comment: The microscopic energy is not the same before and after! Before the collision it will be lower than after. The total energy (microscopic and macroscopic) is the same before and after the collision. If you look at the microscopic energy alone, it will be higher after the collision. But only by the amount that the macroscopic energy is lowered. Does that clear it up?

Comment: I asked prof David Tong and he confirmed: "It is true that, classically, on a microscopic level both kinetic energy and momentum are conserved."

Comment: I think that this statement uses “microscopic” for all microscopic movements which includes the macroscopic movements of the two bodies in question. So what I meant above with “microscopic” is the difference between total and macroscopic energy. I'll reword my answer a bit to make that clear. — If you want, you can tell Mr. Tong “Thank you“ for his QFT lecture notes from me, they are a good read :-)

Comment: Martin, Thank you for this precise and clear answer !